# Print the position of fields form csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a problem.

i have an csv file where i should look at the 5 first lines. Line 1-4 contain metadata. Line 1 is the list of fields of the css file. 
The queastion is

Print the position of the fields, for example:

0 URI

1 rdf-schema#label

2 rdf-schema#comment

3 basedOn_label

4 basedOn

5 budget

how do i do that

Comment: Please put the code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask to help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) can help you:

```
>>> seasons = ['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter']
>>> list(enumerate(seasons))
[(0, 'Spring'), (1, 'Summer'), (2, 'Fall'), (3, 'Winter')]
>>> list(enumerate(seasons, start=1))
[(1, 'Spring'), (2, 'Summer'), (3, 'Fall'), (4, 'Winter')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Generating an example CSV:

```
$ cat << EOF > the.csv
> URI, basedOn, budget
> 1, 2, 3
> 4, 5, 6
> EOF
```

Python code to do what you want

```
fh = open('the.csv', 'r')
line = fh.readline().strip().split(',')
for pos, field in enumerate(line):
    print pos, field

# ... continue reading the rest of `fh`
```

Output on my console:

```
0 URI
1  basedOn
2  budget
```